# Refresh default migrations

Tags: 8, migrations, updating

I done a migration of a website, but new content were created during I done that. So how can I refresh default migrations created by the drush command :

```
drush @alias  migrate-upgrade --legacy-db-url=mysql://user:pass@localhost/d6ce --legacy-root=http://d6-site.vmdev --configure-only
```

I know about the `update` option for `drush mim "migration"` but here, I need to recreate migration.
Perhaps I just need to re-run the original command ?

Thanks

EDIT:
the way seem to be:

```
- drush @alias mr "migration_name"(rollback migration)
 - drush @alias mrs "migration_name"(set to Idle)
 - drush @alias migrate-upgrade XXX (re-create migration)
```

EDIT2:
I get an error on a content type:

```
Drupal\Core\Database\IntegrityConstraintViolationException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '591' for key 'node__vid': INSERT   [error]
INTO {node} (nid, vid, type, uuid, langcode) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3,
:db_insert_placeholder_4); Array
(
    [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 494
    [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 591
    [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => page_europe
    [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => 95cc248e-6c93-4cfa-ad29-b19db86425c5
    [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => fr
)
 in Drupal\Core\Database\Connection->handleQueryException() (line 683 of /var/www/drupal-8/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Connection.php).
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '591' for key 'node__vid': INSERT INTO {node} (nid, vid, type, uuid, langcode) VALUES           [error]
(:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4); Array
(
    [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 494
    [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 591
    [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => page_europe
    [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => 95cc248e-6c93-4cfa-ad29-b19db86425c5
    [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => fr
)
 (/var/www/drupal-8/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php:783)
Processed 31 items (30 created, 0 updated, 1 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'd6_node:page_europe'                                                                     [status]
d6_node:page_europe Migration - 1 failed.
```

With or without roolback...no issue on another content type.Related to taxonomy ? How can I fix that ?
I notify that if I just run: drush @alias ms I get this kind of infos:

```
upgrade_d6_file      Idle  1521   1497      21         2018-10-29 14:57:40
```

So new files are mentionned and would be able to be imported as is with --update option ,not ?

Answer (score 0):

I needed something similar, I solved it by first making a rollback and then I launched the original command.

`drush mr`

You can find more information about the command on this link  https://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/migrate/migrate-rollback/